# Is it possible to find out whether two instances are of the same RDF class, programmatically?

Tags: java, rdf, semantic-web, jena

Is it possible to find out whether two instances are of the same class, programmatically (Using api such as JENA)

Comment: Can you use pure Java methods?

Comment: Why Jena?  You can easily get the `.class` of the two objects and compare them.

Comment: I don't think the question concerns java instances and classes, but RDF / OWL instances and classes.

Comment: user205512: you are right, I would like to compare RDF/OWL instances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy in SPARQL:

```
ASK { <instance1> a ?class . <instance2> a ?class . }
```

In Jena API:

```
boolean shareClass = false;
for (Statement s: instance1.listProperties(RDF.type)) {
    if (instance2.hasProperty(RDF.type, s.getObject()) {
        shareClass = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Not very elegant.

Comment: Now that SPARQL 1.1 has property paths, the SPARQL query simplifies to `ASK { ?class ^a <instance1>, <instance2> }`.  It captures very well "is there a class of which both instance1 and instance2 are instances?"

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using the Jena ontology API, it's pretty straightforward. Note that in RDF, a given instance can have many types, so your question is really *"how can I test if two instances have one or more types in common?"*.

I would do it as follows. Assume the two instances you want to test are `Individual` objects (note that you can do this with `OntResource`, or even `Resource` with a slight change in the code):

```
Individual i0 = ....;
Individual i1 = ....;
```

List the `rdf:type` values for each, and convert them to sets

```
Set<Resource> types0 = i0.listRDFTypes( false ).toSet();
Set<Resource> types1 = i1.listRDFTypes( false ).toSet();
```

They have types in common if the intersection is non-empty:

```
types0.retainAll( types1 );
if (!types0.isEmpty()) {
    // at least one type in common
    // types0 contains the common type resources
}
```

Comment: That is more pleasant. Guava has `Sets.intersection` which would be even more readable. Typo: `...types1 = i1.listRDFTypes...`

Comment: Hi, I still have some confusion. Hope you can clear that out. As you suggested I get the types and compare their intersection. The problem is: for instances of two different classes the `listRDFTypes` still returns `[http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class]` as a type. As a result, any two instances I take are of same type. Am I missing something?

Comment: If a resource has `rdf:type` `owl:Class`, it *is* a class not an instance of a class. Or there's something unusual or broken in your modelling. If you are convinced that having `rdf:type owl:Class` is correct for your domain model, then you could filter out `owl:Class` from the set. If this isn't enough of an explanation, please prepare a *minimal* example of the problem (code and data) and email it to the jena-users support list at Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Compare their classes:

```
boolean same = obj1.getClass().equals(obj2.getClass());
```

Comment: The OP was not 100% clear about this, but the question most likely concerns RDF/OWL classes and instances, not Java class comparison.

Answer (score -1):

I take it this is an extension to your earlier post so

```
if (resource1.hasProperty(model.createProperty("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#", "type"), model.createResource("http://typeUri")) && resource2.hasProperty(model.createProperty("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#", "type"), model.createResource("http://typeUri"))) {
    // both resources are the same type
}
```